# Paypal Cordova Plugin - can't log in and pay with personal account

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

Here is my service

```
angular.module('starter.services').factory('PaypalService', function ($q, $ionicPlatform, shopSettings, $filter, $timeout) {


var init_defer;

 var service = {
  initPaymentUI: initPaymentUI,
  createPayment: createPayment,
  configuration: configuration,
  onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
  makePayment: makePayment
};

return service;

function initPaymentUI() {

init_defer = $q.defer();
$ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {

  var clientIDs = {
    "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": shopSettings.payPalProductionId,
    "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": shopSettings.payPalSandboxId
  };
  PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit);
});

return init_defer.promise;

} 



function createPayment(total, name) {

// "Sale  == >  immediate payment
// "Auth" for payment authorization only, to be captured separately at a later time.
// "Order" for taking an order, with authorization and capture to be done separately at a later time.
var payment = new PayPalPayment("" + total, "USD", "" + name, "Sale");
return payment;
}

function configuration() {
// for more options see `paypal-mobile-js-helper.js`
var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: shopSettings.payPalShopName});
return config;
}

 function onPayPalMobileInit() {
  $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
  // must be called
  // use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
  PayPalMobile.prepareToRender(shopSettings.payPalEnv, configuration(),   function () {

    $timeout(function () {
      init_defer.resolve();
    });

  });
  });
 }


function makePayment(total, name) {


var defer = $q.defer();
total = $filter('number')(total, 2);
$ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
  PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(total, name), function (result) {
    $timeout(function () {
      defer.resolve(result);
    });
  }, function (error) {
    $timeout(function () {
      defer.reject(error);
    });
  });
});

return defer.promise;
 }
})
```

and my settings

```
.constant('shopSettings',{
  payPalSandboxId : 'id',
  payPalProductionId : 'id',
  payPalEnv: 'PayPalEnvironmentSandbox',
  payPalShopName : 'app_name'
});
```

All I need is to make standard payment for user, so some user can log in in personal account, pay for some stuff and money will appear in my account.By the way everything works fine if I log in with sandbox test accounts, but not with real one's.

Comment: What is the request result? Where is your account from? I've had a similar problem and it was a country restriction from paypal.

Comment: @Necroside Buyer account is from Ukraine so is mine. It just doesn't let me to log in in some account to make payment except sandbox testing account